# A continuous optimization problem that reduces to TSP

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, optimization, computable-analysis

Suppose I am given a  finite set of points $p_1,p_2,..p_n$ in the plane, and asked to draw a twice-differentiable curve $C(P)$ through the $p_i$'s, such that its perimeter is as small as possible. Assuming $p_i=(x_i,y_i)$ and $x_i<x_{i+1}$, I can formalize this problem as:

*Problem 1 (edited in response to Suresh's comments)* Determine  $C^2$ functions $x(t),y(t)$ of a parameter $t$ such that the arclength $ L = \int_{[t \in 0,1]} \sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}dt$  is minimized, with $x(0) = x_1, x(1) = x_n$ and for all $t_i: x(t_i) = x_i$, we have $y(t_i)=y_i)$.

> How do I prove (or perhaps refute) that Problem 1 is NP-hard?

*Why I suspect NP-hardness*    Suppose the $C^2$ assumption is relaxed. Evidently, the function of minimal arclength is the Travelling Salesman tour of the $p_i$'s.  Perhaps the $C^2$ constraint only makes the problem much harder?

*Context*  A variant of this problem was posted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23181/extremal-curve-passing-through-a-set-of-points). It didn't receive an answer both there and on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58885/extremal-curves-with-a-should-pass-through-constraint). Given that it's nontrivial to solve the problem, I want to establish how hard it is.

Comment: The constraint that $x_i < x_{i+1}$ seems to make the problem much easier. In particular, if you now drop the $C_2$ constraint, why is this problem not trivially solved because you connect the points by straight lines ?

Comment: Not quite. Given $p_1,p_2,p_3$, the TSP could be $p_1p_3p_2$ and not $p_1p_2p_3$

Comment: That's not a function. If you "loop around" from $p_3$ to $p_2$, under the constraint that $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$, your curve will intersect a vertical line twice.

Comment: edited suitably

Comment: ok. also, I think what you really need is that $x_i \ne x_j$ for all $j \ne i$. The ordering doesn't really matter.

Comment: What do you mean by "determine"? Remember that a function is a infinite object, classical complexity theory deals only with finite inputs/outputs. I am guessing that you are looking for something like spline (in which case I suggest that we add the [tag:numerical-analysis] tag to the question, if really looking for arbitrary functions then use the [tag:computable-analysis] tag.)

Comment: ps: it seems that the copy on MO has an accepted answer.

Comment: @Kaveh: the question should be very clear. This is not about splines or numerical analysis. I have changed the MO link.

Comment: It is not clear, you need to state what you mean by "determine" here. It is not a standard terminology. It is not even a decision problem so using the term NP-hard doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you please help me with the definition of 'determine' and 'standard' terminology?

Comment: NP-hardness doesn't need a decision problem (see all optimization problems)

Comment: @Suresh, can explain the question if you understand it? What is the input and what is the output?

Comment: Input is a set of points. Output is a parametrically described curve (and I agree that restricting to splines makes sense for the complexity question) of minimum length etc etc

Comment: @Suresh, can you expand on the output part? I am guessing that you mean outputting the name of a curse from a enumerable set of curves. Note that in that case, it is not clear that the optimal curve will always be from that class. On the other hand, if we mean to find the best or a good one between those (or an approximation up to some given parameter to the optimal curve) then the class of parametric curves should be specified, otherwise the question is incomplete and cannot be answered.

Comment: ps: this is the kind of questions that numerical-analysts study, though they usually don't talk about complexity class of the problems they study since their algorithms often works only when the input/output are "nice".

Comment: On the other hand, if what you really interested in is drawing the result, then the right approach in my humble opinion is to consider a dense class of curves (w.r.t. some metric) (e.g. piece-wise linear functions) and ask about an algorithm to find an $\epsilon$-approximation in a metric to the optimal from that class. This is what people really do in practice, you can find articles about similar problems like convex hall in computable analysis. If you want to know the complexity of that problem,

Comment: then note that the problem is not a classical computational problem but a higher-type problem, and higher-type complexity classes is not much explored, we know the complexity of a few higher-type problems.

Comment: thanks for the comments. Can you give an example of higher-type?

Comment: The input/output is not a finite object anymore, e.g. if you are *really* dealing with real numbers/functions then your problem is higher-type. Each infinite objects are given by an infinite series of approximations to the intended object. [CCA network](http://cca-net.de/)'s page contains more links if you are interested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The differentiability requirement doesn't change the nature of the problem: requiring $\mathcal{C}^0$ (continuity) or $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ (infinite differentiability) gives the same lower bound for the length and the same order of points, and is equivalent to solving the traveling salesman problem.

If you have a solution to the TSP, you have a $\mathcal{C}^0$ curve that goes through all the points. Conversely, suppose you have a $\mathcal{C}^0$ curve of finite length that goes through all the points, and let $p_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, p_{\sigma(n)}$ be the order in which it traverses the points and $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ the corresponding parameters (if the curve traverses a point more than once, pick any of the possible values of $t$). Then the curve built from $n$ segments $[p_{\sigma(1)},p_{\sigma(2)}], \ldots, [p_{\sigma(n-1)},p_{\sigma(n)}], [p_{\sigma(n)},p_{\sigma(1)}]$ is shorter, because for each segment a straight line is shorter than any other curve that connects the point. Thus for every ordering of the points, the best curve is a TSP solution, and the TSP solution provides the best ordering of the points.

Let's now show that requiring the curve to be $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ (or $\mathcal{C}^k$ for any $k$) doesn't change the best ordering of points. For any TSP solution of total length $\ell$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, we can round every corner, i.e. build a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ curve that traverses the points in the same order and has a length of at most $\ell + \epsilon$ (the explicit construction relies on algebraic functions and $e^{-1/t^2}$ to define [bump functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BumpFunction.html) and from those smooth connections between curve segments such as $e^{1-1/x^2} (x-e^{-1/(1-x)^2})$ which connects with $y=0$ at $x=0$ and with $y=x$ at $x=1$; it is tedious to make these explicit, but they are computable); hence, the lower bound for a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ curve is the same as for a collection of segments (note that the lower bound is not reached in general).

Comment: This is *exactly* the argument I was looking for , for a long time! Can you give a reference for the tedious construction?

Comment: This is not entirely rigorous, especially since in the plane you can get an arbitrarily good approximation to TSP in polynomial time.

Comment: I thought you could approximate TSP only to within a factor of 2 in poly time?

Comment: @PKG The construction probably has a name, but I'm afraid my calculus classes were too long ago for me to remember it. I've just remembered the basic connection is called a bump function.

Comment: @Suresh Where's my mistake? I'm showing that $C^\infty$ TSP is equivalent to straight-lines TSP (i.e. TSP for planar Euclidian graphs); I'm not claiming anything about the difficulty of the latter problem, but an answer that addressed that would be interesting.

Comment: It's not a mistake per se. Your reduction is approximate - upto some error term $\epsilon$. This matters, because the reduction might be expensive (i.e exponential in $1/\epsilon$). So the reduction is not exact. @PKG you can approximate TSP to factor 3/2 in general metric spaces and arbitrarily close (to within $1+\epsilon$) in the plane or any Euclidean space.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you are saying is that the order will be the same as original TSP, outputting the order the points are visited is going to NP-hard. Very nice answer. :)

Comment: ps: btw, we may not need to know the order that points are visited to draw an approximation of the optimal curve.

Comment: @Suresh: You can get a (1+ε)-approximation for arbitrary _constant_ ε in polynomial time.  That's not quite the same thing as "an arbitrarily good approximation"; suppose $\varepsilon < 1/2^n$.

Comment: @JeffE granted. but my only complaint was that the claim about the original approximation lacked details about the dependence on epsilon